# norm squared of imaginary function with unknown constants

Tags: equation-solving

Is it possible to evaluate the norm squared and expand a given function similar to this,
$$
c(t)=\frac{-e^{-iat}}{2}-\bigg[\big(\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}{4\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}\big)e^{-\frac{i}{2}(a-\sqrt{a^2+16b^2})t}\bigg]+\bigg[\big(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}{4\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}\big)e^{-\frac{i}{2}(a+\sqrt{a^2+16b^2})t}\bigg]
$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $a,b$ are real constants

$e^{-iat}=cos(at)-i.sin(at)$

$e^{-\frac{i}{2}(a-\sqrt{a^2+16b^2})t}=cos\big((\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}{2})t\big)-i.sin\big((\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}{2})t\big)$

$e^{-\frac{i}{2}(a+\sqrt{a^2+16b^2})t}=cos\big((\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}{2})t\big)-i.sin\big((\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+16b^2}}{2})t\big)$

If possible how do I do that ?

Comment: Please enter your function in a code block using proper Mathematica syntax. Are `a` and `b` complex constants or real constants? Is `t` complex or real?

Comment: @BobHanlon $a, b$ are real constants , $t$ is a variable which is real and $c$ is a function of $t$, i.e. $c(t)$

Comment: @BobHanlon pls check. I have edited the original question.

Comment: You have not put your code in proper Mathematica syntax in code blocks. It is unreasonable to expect anyone trying to help you to have to reformat and retype your equations rather than being able to copy and paste.

Comment: @BobHanlon well..I'm srry, but I'm very new to Mathematica. It'd be very helpful if you could give me some hint, how to enter the code for this.

Comment: Enter equations in a Mathematica notebook using proper [syntax](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html). Convert cell to `InputForm`. Copy and paste cell into MSE. Highlight pasted text and press `{}` icon to convert to code block (or indent four spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : Corrected sign error in first term

Define the function

```
c[t_] = -E^(-I a t)/
    2 - (a - 
       Sqrt[a^2 + 16 b^2])/(4 Sqrt[a^2 + 16 b^2]) E^(-I/
        2 (a - Sqrt[a^2 + 16 b^2]) t) + (a + 
       Sqrt[a^2 + 16 b^2])/(4 Sqrt[a^2 + 16 b^2]) E^(-I/
        2 (a + Sqrt[a^2 + 16 b^2]) t);
```

Since `a` and `b` and `t` are real you can use [ComplexExpand](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) on the square of the [Norm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html)

```
n2c[1] = Norm[c[t]]^2 // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  FullSimplify

   (*  (1/(2*(a^2 + 16*b^2)))*
   (a^2 + 12*b^2 - (a^2 + 16*b^2)*
        Cos[(a*t)/2]*
        Cos[(1/2)*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*
            t] + 4*b^2*
        Cos[Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*t] - 
      a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*
        Sin[(a*t)/2]*
        Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*t])  *)
```

For an alternate representation,

```
n2c[2] = n2c[1] // TrigExpand // FullSimplify

(*  (1/2)*(1 - Cos[(a*t)/2]*
        Cos[(1/2)*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*
            t] + 
      (4*b^2*(-1 + Cos[
                Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*t]))/
        (a^2 + 16*b^2) - 
      (a*Sin[(a*t)/2]*
           Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*
               t])/Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])  *)
```

Comparing the complexity of the different representations

```
LeafCount /@ (n2c /@ Range[2])

(*  {124, 110}  *)
```

Verifying that the representations are equivalent

```
Equal @@ (n2c /@ Range[2]) // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```